# Postgres array contains any from another array?

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to perform a query that returns a row if the array column type contains at least one entry from another array, so example:

```
Row1

col_a = {1,2}
```

I want to a query that says `col_a contains {3,1}` and it should return Row1 because col_a contains '1'.

The value {3,1} in the example will come from another subquery. I am not sure this is possible, and I am struggling to find an example. The closest I found was the `@>` operator but that requires all entries to be in col_a right rather than any matching?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `&&` (overlap) operator

```sql
select array[1,2,3,4] && array[3,9];
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Fantastic I missed this operator thank you